# Consider the word 'PARTING'. What is the probability that a 4 letter sequence from this word contain the letter 'P'?

Tags: probability

So far, I only have $_7C_4$ as the total amount of ways to arrange this (35).

The answer is 4/7, and I can't really see how you get there.

Comment: Calculate the probability of the counterevent, i.e. that a four letter sequence from this word doesn't contain the letter 'P'. For the first element of this sequence, you have six possibilities, for the second ... Then divide by all possibilities to get an arbitrary four letter sequence. Subtracting the result from one gives you the probability you're searching for.

Answer (score 1):

$4$ of the $7$ distinct letters are selected and any letter has the same probability to be selected. So letter **P** has probability $\frac{4}{7}$ to belong to these $4$.

More formally you could say that if $L_{i}$ denotes the $i$-th letter that is elected then: $$\mathbb{P}\left\{ \mathbf{P}\in\left\{ L_{1},L_{2},L_{3},L_{4}\right\} \right\} =\mathbb{P}\left\{ L_{1}=\mathbf{P}\vee L_{2}=\mathbf{P}\vee L_{3}=\mathbf{P}\vee L_{4}=\mathbf{P}\right\} $$$$=\mathbb{P}\left\{ L_{1}=\mathbf{P}\right\} +\mathbb{P}\left\{ L_{2}=\mathbf{P}\right\} +\mathbb{P}\left\{ L_{3}=\mathbf{P}\right\} +\mathbb{P}\left\{ L_{4}=\mathbf{P}\right\} =\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{7}$$

Comment: +1 This is a beautifully correct answer, but some people, especially beginners, have difficulty accepting the idea that in sampling without replacement (as in this case), each letter is equally likely to be chosen as the $i$-th letter. For sampling with replacement, there is no hesitation in accepting this argument, but sampling without replacement often causes difficulty.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thank you. I understand what you mean and hope that my edit will make things more easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You have $7\choose4$ ways to choose a sequence (pick the letters and set them the way they are set in the originial letter), and you have $6\choose3$ ways to choose a sequence containing 'P' (pick the other 3 letters).

Therefore the probability is given by $$\frac {6\choose3} {7\choose4} = \frac47 $$